# Cannot boot from USB to install Linux. Need administrator password that I dont have. Any easy way arround this?

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, passwords

I have made a bootable USB with Elementary on it - in order to erase my Windows 7 and install Linux Elementary. So far so good.

I get the message shown on the photo in the link - indicating that there is an administrator password needed to proceed with booting on the USB:

[image: UEFI boot menu]

It's an old work PC from my previous work so it's difficult to get the password from them.

I tried to reset the firmware password, as I thought that would do. But it didn't work. Same issue so it must be a different password:

[image]

Any ideas ? Any other way to wipe the hole thing including the bios - in order to be able to boot from a USB without password ?

Please bear in mind that I have very limited skills and know very few terms in this field. Hope Someone has an easy way to work around it - in order to get up and running with Linux.

Thanks for your kind assistance in advance.

Comment: What device exactly? Modern computers don't store BIOS/UEFI passwords in standard CMOS, they are stored in special areas of NVRAM that are encrypted. Different models have different ways of clearing the password, and many have NO WAY whatsoever of clearing the password legitimately. The last time I saw this on a HP Probook, it took buying a $25 tool from a very shady online source linked via YouTube to get the tool, but it worked (not a recommendation to do, it was a desperate situation and PayPal has ways around a bad deal).

Comment: I wonder if you could remove the hard drive, do the install on another system, then put it back in.

Answer (score 1):

how did you exactly try to reset the BIOS password?
did you take out the battery or replace the jumper, or even pressed the reset button if there is any?
you should most likely take your laptop apart.
if you would give me the model name of your laptop i could see if i can find a solution.

Okay, I did some research regarding the pictures where i found the model of your laptop.

You should open up the laptop. and search for a jumper (http://img.tomshardware.com/uk/2002/09/04/building_your_own_pc/jumper.jpg) with something like PWD, PSWD, PSWDCLR close to it. There are 2 actions available.

1: if your jumper is set on 2 pins.

```
remove the jumper completely and turn on your laptop/notebook
wait until you see the windows log-in screen and turn it off
then place the jumper back and the password should be reset.
```

2: if your jumper is set on a set of 3 pins

```
Remember where your jumper was set (eg: pin 1 and 2)
place the jumper over to the other side (eg: pin 2 and 3)
turn on the laptop and wait about 5 seconds before turning it off again
Now place the jumper back to the original 2 pins and the password should be reset
```

Greetings Jesse

Comment: Good questions, but this probably should have been a comment and not a full solution answer.

Comment: sorry, i dont have enough reputation yet to comment, so i'm forced to place this as an answer

Comment: Ah. Well, that will solve itself after you get some rep. on this site.

Comment: it will. i also updated the answer since i found out his laptop model was noted in the pictures :)

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions. I tried the BIOS master password site and combined the serial number with "-595B" ,  "-D35B" and "-2A7B" as suggested. Typed in all the corresponding passwords - without luck.

Comment: I will take the PC apart tomorrow and search for a jumper that can reset the BIOS as suggested.

Comment: Good luck ;), and if the model wouldn't have a jumper, you could try taking out the battery and try turning the laptop on without power attached to it(no battery or ac) that might also work since the system wouldn't have backup-power to store that data. But i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize the model number was in the picture... Dell laptops after 2004, like your Latitude e6540 from mid-late 2013, have no legitimate and documented way of clearing the password in hardware. This is a corporate security feature.

> Dell portable systems built in 2004 or later, have NO HARDWARE
>   PASSWORD RESET. To clear a BIOS/HDD password on these systems, you
>   will need to contact Dell Techncial Support.

- [Source](http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/4/SLN133484)

That said, there is a [BIOS Master Password list site](https://bios-pw.org/), that uses research from security experts who researched security exploits and vulnerabilities, it doesn't work with every model, but it might be of use to you.

> Turn over your Dell Latitude and locate the 10-digit service tag on
>   the bottom of the computer.
>
> Sign on to another PC and browse to the BIOS Master Password Generator
>   for Laptops website (see link above).
>
> Enter your service tag into the available field and then click "Get
>   Password" to see the list of backdoor passwords for your BIOS.
>
> Write down the password listed next to "Dell by Serial Number." Turn
>   on your Latitude and enter this password into the prompt to bypass the
>   lock.
>
> Tip
>
> If your service tag is only seven digits long, append "-595B" to the
>   tag and write down the resulting password. Repeat for "-D35B" and
>   "-2A7B." Try each generated password to see which one works.

- [Source](http://yourbusiness.azcentral.com/clear-dell-latitude-bios-password-27246.html)

Otherwise, there are rather shady hack/crack tools, but we do not support or recommend those here.